# Удаление слова из строки Python

Tags: python, строки

Дана строка,

```
a = " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
```

Нужно слово ipsum перенести в конец строки

Comment: done: b = "Lorem dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ipsum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
if "ipsum" in a:
    a = a.replace("ipsum", "", 1) + " ipsum"

print(a)
```